# Deploying iPhone Configuration Profile

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm, configuration-profile

I developed a MDM setup where I could able to push apps into the iOS devices. My main bottleneck here is giving the URL to the user via e-mail and asking them to install configuration profile. I want to automate this process. At once the user login with his Enterprise Wifi's username and password the configuration profile should be installed into the devices.

Comment: This is no answer, but this week's [NSHipster journal](http://nshipster.com/configuration-profiles/) touches upon the topic and might be an interesting to you.

Answer (score 1):

You question is kind of controversial.

You say "where I could able to **push apps** into the iOS devices" and literally next sentence " via **e-mail** and **asking them** to install configuration profile".

It's not clear whether you are sending emails and asking users to install an app or you are pushing an app (meaning that users doesn't have to do anything).

Couple of notes:

1) As I remember, you can't completely automatically it (install apps without a user intervention).

The small caveat - it's possible for supervised devices.

2) If you want to semi-automate it. You can use MDM protocol. As soon as a device is enrolled into MDM server, MDM server can issue install application command and a user will be prompted to install an application. However, ultimately, he/she will decide whether to install it or not

3) Making all of these happen on a user logging to Enterprise WiFi could be even more trickier. I would say, you will need to have a captive portal. You will prompt a user to enroll into MDM on it when he/she connects to this WiFi. And as soon as a user is enrolled, you can install applications + setup client certificate authentication for Enterprise WiFi to distinguish devices which was and wasn't enrolled in MDMD.